# Object won't follow line completely

Tags: arrays, blender, curve, modifier

I am struggling in Blender with the curve tool, my array of fencing that follows this line isn't following it completely. Anyone have any ideas?
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VupQq.png) for image of issue

Comment: Are you referring to the length not being long enough? You can also use Fit Curve in the array modifier to match the length of the curve. You can find better blender help at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Don't worry, there was a break in the CAD line I got given so I fixed it and now it works fine :) thank you though